# Properties of Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

Consider hermitian matrices M1, M2, M3, M4 that obey the property Mi Mj + Mj Mi = 2δij I where I is the identity matrix and i,j=1,2,3,4

a) Show that the eigenvalues of Mi=+/- 1 (Hint: Go to the eigenbasis of Mi and use the equation for i=j)

b) By considering the relation Mi Mi= -Mj Mi for i≠j. Show that Mi are traceless (Hint: Tr(ABC)=Tr(CBA)

c) Show that they cannot be odd dimensional matrices

My attempt:

For part a), det(Mi) det(Mj) + det(Mj) det(Mi) = 2δij det(I) implies 2det(Mi)^2 = 2det(I). This means det(Mi)=+/-1. Since Mi is hermitian and diagonalizable. The diagonalized matrix will have the same determinant with eigenvalues +/-1 therefore the eigenvalues of Mi are +/-1. This is how I think it can be proved, I'm not sure what the hint is telling. For part b) and c) I really don't know how to start.

Comment: The determinant is a nonlinear function, so $\det (A+B) \neq \det(A) + \det (B)$.

Comment: @Titus What does the hint mean by saying go to the eigenbasis? I know that Mi is hermitian and it can be diagonalized to produce a similar matrix that is diagonal, but is this what the hint is pertaining to? The eigenbasis of the similar matrix of the original matrix?

Comment: Since Hermitian matrices are diagonalizable we have $M = U^{-1} D U$ for a unitary matrix $U$ and a diagonal matrix $D = diag(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)$.  If we use this in the equation with $i = j$ we get
$$ 2M_i^2 = 2I $$
$$ M_i^2 = I $$
$$ M_i (U^{-1} U) M_i = I $$
$$ U M_i U^{-1} U M_i U^{-1} = U U^{-1} $$
$$ D_i D_i = I $$
$$ diag(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)^2 = diag(\lambda_1^2, \dots, \lambda_n^2) = diag(1,\dots, 1)$$
which implies that each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ satisfies $\lambda_i^2 = 1$.  This gives part (a).

Comment: @Titus I understand it now, that is really clear. Thanks!!